# Intanstiate entity class using access modifiers in java

Tags: java

I've asked yesterday about the instance generation of java object like `Entity` as the instance variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239761/declare-entity-in-java-as-private

I am not satisfied for the answers I get and now I want to more clarify what my question is:

I have `Entity` called `User.java`:

```
@Entity(naming = NamingType.SNAKE_LOWER_CASE)
public class User{

private String name;

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }
 }
```

And I have a class called `UserImpl.java` what I did is:

```
 public class UserImpl implements UserLogic {

       private User userEntity = new User(); ------> // Bad practice

       /** Methods **/
 }
```

As you can see I declared an instance for User entity in UserImpl class. Is that a bad practice at all?

Any answers will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why would it be bad practice? What specifically is 'bad practice'?

Comment: @Dana, My prof said that it was a bad practice because the value might be  uncertain. And the current state depends on other methods.

Comment: What value *specifically*? And why don't you go to office hours and politely ask them to explain themselves? Further, I think it's better to edit your last question than ask another based on the other. You didn't get any answers because you weren't clear enough and this isn't much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple act of creating a private instance of a class in another class is not a bad practice at all. In fact, it is very common and Java would really be pointless if you couldn't do this.

I feel like there is still some missing information here. Depending on the function of the "UserImpl" class, this might be a bad practice. But this would entirely depend on how you go about implementing the "UserImpl" class.

For example, if you were planning on creating a variety of methods in the "UserImpl" class that would all center around changing "userEntity," then that might be a bad idea because all of those methods could instead go into the "User" class itself, which would be much simpler and more intuitive.

tldr: This isn't bad practice as it is right now, but depending on the purpose of your "UserImpl" class, it could turn out to be.